# Include SVG using ST3 latextools build system

Tags: mac, svg, sublime-text, inkscape

I am trying to include SVG into my document using the SVG package. On OSX Yosemite, I use Sublime Text 3 with the LatexTools Package, BasicTex 2015 and Inkscape installed via Homebrew Cask. Additional missing Tex packages as the SVG package are installed using `tlmgr`. The `inkscape` command is available, as a symlink `/usr/local/bin/inkscape` has been created automatically by homebrew.

Here is my minimal example, taken and even simplified from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includesvg{test}
  \caption{svg test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`test.svg` is a very simple graphic and the file is in the same directory as `test.tex`. As proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178804/17013) I added the following lines to the `builder_settings`:

```
"program": "pdflatex",
"command": ["latexmk", "-cd", "-e", "$pdflatex = '%E -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O'", "-f", "-pdf"],
```

I even tried to mess around with the path definitions in `svg.sty` from as proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158571/includesvg-does-not-detect-svg-file#comment362231_158612) but still, the build engine obviously is not able to use Inkscape to generate the pdf and tex files. This is the ST console output:

```
[Compiling /Users/mcnesium/Desktop/ma/tex/test.tex]
SimpleBuilder: pdflatex run 1; done.
Errors:
./test.tex:7: LaTeX Error: File `./test' not found. [      \includesvg{test}]
./test.tex:7: LaTeX Error: File `./test' not found. [      \includesvg{test}]
./test.tex:7: LaTeX Error: File `test.pdf_tex' not found. [      \includesvg{test}]
[Done!]
```

Who has a similar setup and can point me to whats wrong with mine?

Comment: have you tried with `\includesvg{test.svg}`?

Comment: yes, the output then is: LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg. [      \includesvg{test.svg}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that at least in my setup the `inkscape` command only works when using **absolute paths** to both the input and the output file (see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1426286)). This propably screws up the functionality of the SVG Package.

So I worte this bash script that I fire up just after hitting save on `testsvg.svg` in Inkscape:

```bash
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

dirname=$(dirname "$1");
fullpath=$(cd "$dirname" && pwd -P)/;
inputfile=$(basename "$1");
filename=${inputfile%.*}

svg="$fullpath$inputfile";
pdf="$fullpath$filename".pdf;

$(which inkscape) -z -C -f $svg -A $pdf --export-latex;
```

The following part is optional. I use it because my svg files reside in a sub-directory of my main tex file. So on build the references in the *.pdf_tex files to the *.pdf file need to have the sub-directory appended, which the following does:

```bash
$(which sed) -i 's/'"$filename.pdf"'/'"$dirname\/$filename.pdf"'/g' "$pdf"_tex;
```

In the TeX-file I reference it using

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
        \input{figures/testsvg.pdf_tex}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Make sure that the SVG file has a different name than the TeX file, otherwise the output PDF will be mixed up with the Inkscape helper PDF.

This is not as cool as just having the ST Build System do it, but better than always saving as PDF and SVG back and forth in Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know anything about the svg package, but I do know a few things about LaTeXTools.

First, from your console output, you have set your `builder` setting to `simple` in `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` which means that the `command` setting you set is ignored. Since the `simple` builder does not support changing the options passed to `pdflatex` and you need to pass `--shell-escape`, you should set this back to `default`.

Second, the `PATH` for graphical programs on OSX is... annoying to say the least. The work-around supplied by `LaTeXTools` is the `texpath` setting in the `Platform settings` section of `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings`. You need to ensure that the `texpath` includes the path to wherever you installed `Inkscape` is this is necessary for the svg package. I think it should be, but its best to check. (Note that you will see the default setting includes `$PATH` but this is usually not the same as the `$PATH` on your shell. To see what this `$PATH` will expand to, on the Sublime console run: `import os; os.environ['PATH']`.)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, this does not make things much different. With `builder` set to  `default` it just says `TraditionalBuilder: Invoking latexmk... done.` followed by the same errors. When setting it to `script` there is no output at all in the ST3 console.

Comment: The `script` builder actually doesn't do anything, so that's pretty much expected. Did you verify the `PATH` as well? If the `PATH` isn't correct, `pdflatex` won't be able to launch `inkscape`.

Comment: From trying this out, it looks like you should have a line in your log like this: `runsystem(inkscape -z -C -f./test.svg -A./test.pdf --export-latex)...executed`. Can you verify that you have that too?

Comment: the line says `"texpath" : "$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin"` which includes the path to the inkscape symlink mentioned above. Having set `"display_log" : true`,  [here is the log for {test}](https://gist.github.com/mcnesium/9441152cc8895258db55) and [here for {test.svg}](https://gist.github.com/mcnesium/017e86024a4987c33c97?short_path=971a054)

Comment: Can I provide any other information?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that it must be somehow related to your Inkscape install. What happens if you try to run the following two commands from a terminal shell: first, `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin` followed by `inkscape -z -C -f./test.svg -A./test.pdf --export-latex` in the directory in which your svg file is stored. The order is important: I'm trying to simulate the `$PATH` as LaTeXTools sees it.

Comment: Inkscape on OS X I think depends on having a version of X11 installed. Wherever your X11 is installed is probably not on the PATH that LaTeXTools sets. I **think** this can be fixed by adding `/opt/X11` to the end of the `"texpath"` setting, but I'm not entirely sure... I don't have XQuartz or Inkscape installed on my Mac to test with.

Comment: I just figured out that the inkscape command you provided on my system only works with absolute paths to both the input and the output file.