# Customize build setting (LatexTools in Sublime 3)

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

I am using LatexTools in Sublime 3, Windows 10, Miktex 2.9. When I call the command `Build with: Latex - Traditional`, it automatically revoke `-texify` and everything is working OK.

But what I hope is to add the parameter `-cp` to `texify`, which has the effect to automatically delete all the aux files after compiling.
(The following syntax work perfectly in Command Prompt:

```
textify --pdf -cp myfile.tex
```

Following the suggestion in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170723/custom-build-settings-in-sublime), I have tried to edit  `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` as follows:

```
"builder_settings" : {

    // General settings:
    // See README or third-party documentation

    // (built-ins): true shows the log of each command in the output panel
    "display_log" : false,

    "options": ["-cp"],

    // Platform-specific settings:
    "osx" : {
        // See README or third-party documentation
    },

    "windows" : {
        // See README or third-party documentation
    },

    "linux" : {
        // See README or third-party documentation
    }
},
```

But I got no success. The error notification is `Could not read log file myfile.log`.

Please kindly instruct me a solution for that issue. Many thanks.

Comment: The `-c` option deletes the logfile. Therefore LaTeXTools can't find it and complains about this.
You may also think about whether the cleanup shortcut `C-l, backspace` might be sufficient for you.

Comment: Thanks. I got a solution. Edit `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` with: `"command": ["texify", "-cp",  "--engine=%E"],` . It successfully creates PDF file. But the notification `Could not find Log` still shows. Any one might help to suggest any better way? Thanks.