# Showing .log files for debug with Sublime Text with LaTeXTools

Tags: sublime-text, logging, latextools

I try to configure Sublime Text 4 with LaTeXTools to write LaTeX documents. I want to see the .log files for debug purposes (I want to see those files like other editors like TeXniCcenter or TeXmaker). I followed those tutorials : http://individual.utoronto.ca/dobronyi/latexsublime.html ; https://www.danielherber.com/guides.php?option=latex-st3 and I found this post : [Customize build setting (LatexTools in Sublime 3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525817/customize-build-setting-latextools-in-sublime-3) but it didn't help. I modified the LaTeX.sublime-settings file by removing .log files from the `temp_file_exts` variable and setting the `display_log` to `true`.

How can I see .log file for debug after compiling my .tex files please ?

Comment: Can you find the log-file and open it separately with some editor?

Comment: I found an answer on this post : https://evgenii.com/blog/creating-pdf-from-latex-in-sublime-text-3/ It is possible to see the .log file if it wasn't deleted by asking for the builds results. But you are right too, I didn't think about this.